# rsync server, uploaded files permissions incorrect

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to setup an rsync server on my Ubuntu machine.  Transfer from a local PC to the server via rsync does work, but the resultant uploaded files have no r,w or x bits set, e.g.

```
---------- 1 fredb fredb    0 Aug 30 20:50 sk_upgrade_20120830_033450.txt
---------- 1 fredb fredb    0 Aug 30 20:50 sk_user_20120827_184534.txt
---------- 1 fredb fredb    0 Aug 30 20:50 sk_user_20120830_033450.txt
```

My rsyncd.conf file is:

```
motd file = /etc/rsyncd.motd

[workspace]
path = /tmp
comment = rsync server
uid = nobody
gid = nobody
read only = false
auth users = fredb
secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.scrt
```

How can I get the target files permissions correct?
Also once I've solved this problem how can I transfer without a password?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Removing the password is easy, just remove `auth users` and `secrets file` from the configuration (and use some other way to protect rsync from stray people).  The question of why you are ending up with 0 byte files with no permissions is hard.  Is the "local PC" windows based?